# Preserving form values on redirects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, redirect

I have a form that creates a new PlanEntry.

At the top of this form I have this link to upload a video as part of the PlanEntry:

`<%= link_to "Upload Video", new_video_sources_path %>`

This takes a user to another form to upload the video. When successful, it returns back to the new PlanEntry form.

This works fine if the user always starts by uploading a video, but in some instances they may already draft things like a 'title' and 'description'. In these cases, these values are lost when the user returns to the form after uploading the video.

How can I preserve these values?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but in a bit of a roundabout way. Basically I replaced the line above with this:

```
<%= f.submit "Upload Video", :name=>"commit", :value=>"Upload Video" %>
```

This is a second button to submit the PlanEntry form. Now in my controller I check to see which button was clicked in the submission. If it was the "Upload Video" button, I save all the parameters to the session, and redirect to the upload video form.

```
   if params[:commit] == "Upload Video"
    session[:plan_entry] = params[:plan_entry]
    redirect_to new_video_sources_path
   else
    ...
   end
```

When the video is uploaded it redirects back to the new PlanEntry form. In my PlanEntry#new controller I check if there are existing session variables. If so, I grab them and then clear them.

```
  if session[:plan_entry].present?
    @plan_entry.assign_attributes(session[:plan_entry])
    session[:plan_entry] = nil
  end
```